# Google Sheets: insert a non http protocol link?

Tags: google-sheets

I use the Chrome extension *Session Buddy* to store browsing sessions. In this case, I saved a few windows with tabs on a search I just did but will read later.

So, on a Sheet where I keep notes to read later I'd like to link this sheet to that saved session, to easily reload when time allows.

So, the link I want to insert is:
`=hyperlink("chrome-extension://edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko/main.html#VDNNy652XdoPqvxr6QKLfnZ6hyhHzM0M","My link label")`

Sheets will not treat this as a valid link, it won't output a link (just text). And says *Link doesn't look right. Typo?* if I use the link input form. I assume only *http* protocol links are supported ?

Workaround?: Perhaps, although hacky, use some kind of **proxy** or **url re-writing** technique?  I'm a web dev, so I could implement this sort of hack, say simply if my proxy / router sees any link such as `http://my-url-change/link123` would re-write (locally, on my LAN) to any of my desired non-http links (such as file://, etc) ? Makes sense, anyone ? If so, I'll try that and share findings here.

### Trials (ongoing):

- I tried with a URL re-writing extension called `requestly`, which seems perfect for this kind of task. But so far no joy, it does not work. I don't understand why, perhaps a browser restart needed ? I'll update this later...

Comment: This is also the same case with Gmail and google-calendar which is very frustrating. I would rather have my `zoommtg` links directly open the zoom app rather than what Zoom is having to do now (go to http website just to redirect to a local link!). I wonder if a Firefox or Chrome extension could resolve this somehow.

Answer (score 1):

The local (i.e. non-http) url can be shortened via [TinyURL](https://tinyurl.com/) (or some other URL shortening service; although for example [bitly](https://bitly.com/) does not support non-standard URLs), which will provide a standard `https` link that can be used anywhere, and after opening is correctly redirected to the local url, which then opens the app.

Comment: Thanks, it's a good suggestion, in theory, but it didn't work on those two services. Any ideas where to find one ?